# RPS: Cannot import name ExporterIFCUtils

Tags: api, revit, revitpythonshell

With the revitpythonshell 2020 I try to import the class `ExporterIFCUtils`

```
from Autodesk.Revit.DB.IFC import ExporterIFCUtils
```

and get the error:

> "Exception : IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: Cannot import name ExporterIFCUtils"

Answer (score 1):

@StefanAnd you'll need to add a reference to the `RevitAPIIFC.dll` first:

```
>>> clr.AddReference("RevitAPIIFC")

>>> from Autodesk.Revit.DB.IFC import ExporterIFC
>>> ExporterIFC
﻿<type 'ExporterIFC'>
>>>
```

It's a bit weird, since it looks like you're importing from a module, but it's a .NET "namespace". These can span multiple assemblies as in the case here, so first referencing the `RevitAPIIFC.dll` will populate the namespace with the types you expect. Sadly, the Revit API documentation doesn't actually seem to provide the assembly names. At least, I couldn't find them...